# Perform arithmetic operation Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I want to make a query to HBase with Pig. But the rowkeys are stored using reverse timestamp (`Long.MAX_VALUE - timestamp`).
So with my pig script, I want to store in a variable the current date in the format (`LONG.MAX_VALUE - currentTime`) to do the query.

```
LOAD 'MYDATA'
USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('d:column', '-caster=HBaseBinaryConverter -gte $minRowKey* -lte $maxRowKey -loadKey true' )
AS (rowkey:chararray,json:chararray);
```

So I would do something like this:

```
%default maxRowKey "date +%s"
```

And I would like to perform the subtraction `LONG.MAX_VALUE - maxRowKey` to do the query. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know of the existence of HBaseStorage options:

> -minTimestamp= Scan's timestamp for min timeRange
>
> -maxTimestamp= Scan's timestamp for max timeRange

That did the trick for me.